# Pagination in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pagination

How do i limit the result of a query (in my case about 60K rows) and select only from the X row to the Y row?

If I use ROW_NUMBER() I don't like my query because it involves 2 select queries .. one to return the rows and one to select the portion I need

**Update:**

Here's the query I use now:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY E.LastChangeDate DESC) AS row, E.*, U.[DisplayName] AS EntryCreatorDisplayName, U.[Email] AS EntryCreatorEmail
        FROM    entries e
        INNER JOIN
                users u
        ON      e.fk_user= u.id
        WHERE   e.EntryRank = 2
                AND u.Administrator = 1
        ) as TableWithRows
WHERE   (row >= 31 AND row <= 60)
```

Comment: Do you have an identiy column in the table?

Comment: MS SQL 2005, and yes I have an identity column because i have an order by over a arbitrart field in my select

Answer (score 6):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  TOP (@Y) m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycol) AS rn
        FROM    mytable m
        ORDER BY
                mycol
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn >= @X
```

In `SQL Server 2000`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP (@Y - @X) *
        FROM    (
                SELECT  TOP (@X) *
                FROM    mytable
                ORDER BY
                        mycol
                ) q
        ORDER BY
                mycol DESC
        ) q2
ORDER BY
        mycol
```

Comment: I believe this is limited to SQL Server 2005 and up

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight, sorry added that comment before I saw yours

Comment: I used this method but this involves 2 queryes, one to bring all the rows needed (about 60K) and one to limit them to only 30 (in my case). The first select takes a lot of time to execute and this hurts my overall performance.

Comment: `@Paul`: could you please post your query? Probably the query itself needs some improvement.

Comment: SELECT *
      FROM
      (
      SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY  E.LastChangeDate   DESC) AS row, E.*, U.[DisplayName] AS EntryCreatorDisplayName,U.[Email] AS EntryCreatorEmail from entries e inner join users u on e.fk_user= u.id   WHERE e.EntryRank=2 AND  u.Administrator = 1      
      ) as TableWithRows   
         WHERE (row >= 31  AND row <= 60)


The query from the entry table returns about 60K rows and takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: @Paul: try adding the `TOP` as in my first query.

Answer (score 0):

Row_Number() function can be used for this. Please refer to following article for usage
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3572301/RowNumber-function-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

Answer (score 0):

Don't have access to SQL at this very moment, but would something like this work?

```
SELECT tempid=IDENTITY(int, 1, 1), * FROM tbl WHERE tempid >= @x AND tempid <= @y
```

Comment: this is working only if I insert the select into a temporary table ( it was the known workaround before SQL 2005 rownumber)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with MSSQL, But in MySQL, I'd do something like this:

```
LIMIT 50, 10
```

Where 10 is the number of records to skip, and 50 is the number to take.